# "file not found " error while creating a static library in c using gcc - linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, static-libraries

I have a file hello.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void hello()
{
    printf("Hello!\n");
}
```

A header hello.h

```
#ifndef _hello_
#define _hello_

void hello();

#endif
```

main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"

int main()
{

  hello();
  return 0;
}
```

I am currently in the folder /home/user/name/programs

I am trying to build a static library mylib.a. Here is what I do to build it

```
1. gcc -c hello.c 
2. ar rcs mylib.a hello.o
3. gcc -static main.c -L/home/user/name.programs -lib -o hello
```

I get the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My questions are

```
`1. why is gcc searching for the file in the folder /usr/bin - I understand this is   
    what is happening ?
 2. How do I fix this?`
```

Comment: +1. That's the way questions should be asked, very clear with all the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the library name to start with **lib**

```
ar rcs libmy.a hello.o
       ^^^^^^^
gcc -static main.c -L/home/user/name.programs -lmy -o hello
                                              ^^^^^
```

And its not searching in `/usr/bin`,. The error is split by the **linker** (`ld`) which resides in `/usr/bin`.